# Create or update unique method Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following entity:

```
class DoctrinePartnerDao extends DoctrineBaseDao
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    public int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true, nullable: false)]
    public Uuid $guid;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: false)]
    public string $name;

    #[
        ORM\ManyToOne(
            targetEntity: DoctrineCountryDao::class,
            cascade: ['persist']
        )
    ]
    public DoctrineCountryDao $country;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: DoctrineImageDao::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'banner_image_id', nullable: true)]
    public ?DoctrineImageDao $bannerImage = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: DoctrineImageDao::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'avatar_image_id', nullable: true)]
    public ?DoctrineImageDao $avatarImage = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime', nullable: true)]
    public ?DateTimeInterface $deletedAt;
```

And the save method:

```
public function save(Partner $partner): Partner
    {
        /** @var DoctrinePartnerDao */
        $dao = $this->mapper->toDao($partner);
        $countryId = $partner->getCountryId();
        $countryReference = $this->getEntityManager()->getReference(
            DoctrineCountryDao::class,
            $countryId
        );

        if (!$countryReference) {
            throw new InvalidAggregateIdException(
                "Country with id '$countryId' does not exist."
            );
        }

        $bannerImageReference = $partner->getBannerImageId()
            ? $this->getEntityManager()->getReference(
                DoctrineImageDao::class,
                $partner->getBannerImageId()
            )
            : null;

        $avatarImageReference = $partner->getAvatarImageId()
            ? $this->getEntityManager()->getReference(
                DoctrineImageDao::class,
                $partner->getAvatarImageId()
            )
            : null;

        $dao->country = $countryReference;
        $dao->bannerImage = $bannerImageReference;
        $dao->avatarImage = $avatarImageReference;

        try {
          $this->getEntityManager()
            ->persist($dao)
            ->flush();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
         dd($e);
        }

        return $partner;
    }
```

Expected behavior: create the entity in db if it doesn't exist and if it exists update it. I am trying to avoid finding it first.

Before it was a 'merge' method but it seems it is deprecated now.

Getting the following error:
#message: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'i\x03\xE4\xED\x18\xAE8\x18\xB6%\xD1\x18\xD7D\xE6\xBA' for key 'partner.UNIQ_312B3E162B6FCFB2'"

Comment: you need to merge the entity manually ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51206823/how-to-replace-entitymanagermerge-in-doctrine-3

Comment: Just to know, why are you doing this ? I mean, since a find by id is terribly fast, so why would you had such complex case to your codebase. Not judgemental, im asking myself what is the usecase that could need that